# Как проверить существует ли объект

Tags: javascript

Как проверить существует ли глобальный объект? Есть код:

```
function foo() {
    GlobalObj.doSome()
}
```

Надо узнать, существует ли объект. Как я понял, в итоге должно получиться нечто подобное:

```
function foo() {
    ifdef (GlobalObj) {
        GlobalObj.doSome()
    }
}
```

Есть ли разница между

```
if (GlobalObj != undefined) {...}
```

и

```
if (typeof GlobalObj != 'undefined') {...}
```

Можно ли просто использовать блок `try/catch`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть только 3 сравнения с `null` и `undefined` дающие `TRUE`:

```
undefined == undefined;
null == null;
undefined == null;
```

Любые другие комбинации -  `FALSE`

Соответственно:

`if (GlobalObj != undefined) {...}           GlobalObj = ^[ undefined | null ]`

`if (typeof GlobalObj != 'undefined') {...}  GlobalObj = ^[ undefined ]`

Comment: Всегдя советую использовать тройное равенство во избежание **нипанятных ашибак :(**

Answer (score 2):

```
if (typeof GlobalObj !== "undefined" && GlobalObj !== null) 
{...}
```

[typeof === “undefined” vs. != null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703102/typeof-undefined-vs-null)

```
if(typeof neverDeclared == "undefined") //no errors

if(neverDeclared == null) //throws ReferenceError: neverDeclared is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

Можете использовать проверку на undefined:

```
if (GlobalObj != undefined) {...}
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

В определенных случаях есть смысл жестко указать на то что ищем именно глобальную переменную:
`window.GlobalObj`
И в данном случае проверка может быть: 
`if(!window.GlobalObj){...}` 
(если быть уверенным точно что `window.GlobalObj !== false`)

Разница между

```
if (GlobalObj != undefined) {...}
```

и

```
if (typeof GlobalObj != 'undefined') {...}
```

существует :) Если `typeof GlobalObj == 'undefined'`, то в первом случае выбросится ошибка: `ReferenceError: GlobalObj is not defined`