# getElementById прерывает цикл for?

Tags: javascript

Получаю при помощи XMLHttpRequest список ID через разделитель "," у которых нужно изменить цвет бэкграунда, запускаю:

```
readyyes = this.responseText.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < readyyes.length; i++)
{
alert(readyyes[i]);
document.getElementById(readyyes[i]).style.background = 'rgb(247, 80, 80)';
}
```

В этом случае цикл срабатывает 1 раз (alert выдает только 1 элемент массива), а если убираю document.getEl...., то работает нормально и alert запустится столько раз, сколько элементов в массиве.

Почему так?

Comment: в консоле браузера ошибки какие? скорее всего пробел или еще какой-нибудь текст попадает, к которому нельзя применить `style`

Comment: @slippyk, да, вы правы - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null.    А как можно проверять, есть ли такой ID в коде?

Comment: @SuperPonchik  if(document.getElementById(readyyes[i])!=null)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`document.getElementById` возвращает ссылку на объект типа `Element` или `null`, если элемент с указанным `ID` не найден в документе.

[Как проверить существует ли объект](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/55074/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82)

```js
if (!document.getElementById("main")) {
    alert("No");
} else {
    alert("Yes");
}

if (document.getElementById("main") == null) {
    alert("No");
} else {
    alert("Yes");
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все работает.